# IE10 & ASP.Net Handler bug

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httphandler, httpmodule

I tested my site on IE10. View source IE 10 not include some ScriptResource.axd files. But I copy site url and paste chrome work fine.

This code not included IE10.( Right click -> View Source )

```
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: No question mark, no question

Comment: have you tried in previous version of IE?

Comment: Yes i tried IE9,IE8 and IE7. Work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common case when such an issue appears is situation when ASP.NET fails to detect browser as JavaScript capable. In case of IE10 there are KBs which you should have installed on your development machine and servers. Please check if you have them, there are described in details here (with some other fix possibilities):

- [Bug and Fix: ASP.NET fails to detect IE10](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)